# How to get sprite from sprite sheet using pixel array?

Tags: java, image, sprite

I want to get sprites from my sprite sheet using a pixel array of RGB values (in the `.render()` method). The pixel array is supposed to hold the RGB values of the entire image to later be used in order to get the individual sprites from the image. Can someone explain exactly how I can do that? I'm just getting a black image.

Code:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SpritePractice extends Canvas implements Runnable{

private JFrame frame;
public final static int WIDTH = 200, HEIGHT = 200;
public final static int SCALE = 2;
private final static Dimension dimens= new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE);
private BufferedImage image;
private Graphics g;
private long nanoSecond = 1000000000;
private double tick = nanoSecond/60;
private boolean running = false;
private int pixelsFromImage[];
private int pixel[][];
private static DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("[" + "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
        +"]");
private static DateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("[" + "HH:mm:ss" + "]");

public SpritePractice()
{
    frame = new JFrame("Bomberman");
    frame.setSize(dimens);
    frame.setMinimumSize(dimens);
    frame.setMaximumSize(dimens);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(this);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    init();
}
public void init()
{
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("START: " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
}

public void run() 
{
    long now = System.nanoTime();
    long lastTick = System.nanoTime();
    long lastSecond = System.nanoTime();
    int frames = 0;

    while(running)
    {
        now = System.nanoTime();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        if(now-lastTick >= tick)
        {
            lastTick = now;
            tick();
            try {
                render();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            frames++;
        }   
        if(now-lastSecond >= nanoSecond)
        {
            lastSecond = now;
            System.out.println(dateFormat2.format(cal.getTime()) + "FPS: " + frames);
            frames = 0;
        }
    }
}
public void tick()
{
    //updates values
}
public void render() throws IOException
{
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs==null)
    {
        createBufferStrategy(2);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    BufferedImage spriteSheet = new BufferedImage(WIDTH*2,HEIGHT*2, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    try
    {
    spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(new File("/res/MarioSpriteSheet.png"));
    }catch (IOException e)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        pixelsFromImage = ((DataBufferInt) spriteSheet.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    }
    BufferedImage sprite = new BufferedImage(WIDTH*2,HEIGHT*2, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    sprite.getRaster().setPixels(50, 50, 100, 100, pixelsFromImage);

    g.drawImage(sprite,100,100,100,100,null);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
    //renders graphics
}
public synchronized void start()
{
    running = true;
    run();
}
public synchronized void stop()
{
    running = false;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new SpritePractice().start();
}
```

}

UPDATE (1):

-Able to read the file, "MarioSpriteSheet.png" by changing `spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/MarioSpriteSheet.png"));`

to `spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/MarioSpriteSheet.png"));`

(the image res folder was already in CLASS PATH.

New problem:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.awt.image.DataBufferByte cannot be cast to java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
at SpritePractice.render(SpritePractice.java:115)
at SpritePractice.run(SpritePractice.java:75)
at SpritePractice.start(SpritePractice.java:125)
at SpritePractice.main(SpritePractice.java:133)
```

Comment: You should probably print the stacktrace from the try/catch where you read in your sprite sheet. You may have an issue there...

Comment: Whenever you have a `try/catch` block you should always print the stack trace - it'll help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

That code is throwing exceptions here that it then ignores.   Change code of the form

```
catch (Exception e) { 
     ..
```

to:

```
catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! 
    ..
```

Comment: Problem is with the path. The image is in the res folder. What's the fastest way to get it?

Comment: `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/MarioSpriteSheet.png"));`

Comment: Hmm.. now it's giving me IllegalArgumentException: input == null (same line)

Comment: Which Jar contains the `MarioSpriteSheet.png`?  Do a `jar -tvf the.jar` and copy/paste the output as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20014059/edit).

Comment: @AndrewKor That means the file doesn't exist. Make sure you spelt the name of it correctly, you might have accidentally made a spelling mistake.

Comment: No spelling mistakes made. @AndrewThompson: how do I do that? what is jar-tvf the.jar?

Comment: I was referring to the [Jar command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html).  An easier way to check is 1) Rename the Jar from `the.jar` to `the.zip` and 2) open it to 3) examine the content inside.  But I'd prefer you figure out how to do it using SDK tools, if only for the fact it is easier to copy/paste the output for everyone else to see.

Comment: Says "Could not find or load main class jar"

Comment: *Says "Could not find or load main class jar"*  I'm having trouble figuring out 1) How anything in your environment might have changed in the mean-time to cause that message.  2) How that actually relates to the current problem.  --  Note that you should not see SO as a 'one stop - fix my code shop'.  The 'could not find main class' is so different as to deserve its own question.