# ImageIO can't read my file? (input==null)

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio

When I try reading the image from my res folder, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at SpritePractice.render(SpritePractice.java:103)
at SpritePractice.run(SpritePractice.java:71)
at SpritePractice.start(SpritePractice.java:123)
at SpritePractice.main(SpritePractice.java:131)
```

The image itself (MarioSpriteSheet.png) is in the res folder, and I spelled the name right. What's the problem here?

```
BufferedImage spriteSheet = new BufferedImage(WIDTH*2,HEIGHT*2, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    try
    {
    spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/MarioSpriteSheet.png"));
    }catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        pixelsFromImage = ((DataBufferInt) spriteSheet.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you've got access to the folder!

Comment: Duplicate of [How to get sprite from sprite sheet using pixel array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20014059/how-to-get-sprite-from-sprite-sheet-using-pixel-array).  Don't repost the same question over and over..

Comment: Is your res folder in class path? getResourceAsStream only returns null when the resource isn't found, and this is the case here.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: How is it the same question? This question is about reading an image file, the other was finding how to use a pixel array to display a sprite (didn't know what I was doing). Since this problem is so big on its own, I thought it would deserve its own question

Comment: *"How is it the same question?"*  Your previous question came down to 'how to find the image?'..

Comment: No. My question wasn't about 'how to find the image.' My question was about the entire process of getting a sprite from a pixel array of RGB values because I didn't know how to do it (was looking to get input on the most efficient methods.) We just ran into an error on that last question. That single error wasnt solved by you. Seeing that only you were adding comments on trying to fix that error, and not being able to solve it yourself, I thought it'd be best to post it as a separate question. Why is that such a big deal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IllegalArgumentException Input == null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905496/illegalargumentexception-input-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit `/res/` from the filename. If `res` is on the CLASSPATH you shouldn't need it.

Comment: Thanks robin. Worked.